# What does it mean for an Entity to be "fully consumed"?

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

I was reading the [HttpCore documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.3.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#consume%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity%29) and came across this line.

> `public static void consume(HttpEntity entity)
>                           throws IOException`
>
> Ensures that the entity content is fully consumed and the content
>   stream, if exists, is closed.

What does the term "fully consumed" mean?

Answer (score 1):

It means content of the entity enclosed in the message has been read to its logical delineator, which ensures the underling connection is in a consistent state and could be potentially re-used for transmission of subsequent messages.